# Is this possible to handle the universal link before the 302 redirection on iOS?

Tags: ios, deep-linking

Here is the case:
 1. Domain A with `apple-app-site-association` deployed. 
 2. Domain B with `apple-app-site-association` deployed. 
 3. App go to Domain A. 
 4. Domain A respond a 302, and redirect to Domain B.

So, my question is, when App go to Domain A, will the respond 302 ignore the `apple-app-site-association`? So, the app can't direct the Domain A deep link? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

When Universal Links are correctly configured for a domain, the routing into the app is handled *at the OS level.*

This means that if the Domain A Universal Links config is valid, the web URL will never even be requested — you won't get far enough for the 302 redirect to be executed because the app will already be open at that point.